# How to add content to specific grid columns?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have created 6 columns in a CSS Grid layout. I have for 4 items in a list, but want the items to be placed in 2-5 columns. How should I go about it?

```css
#wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

#portfolio-nav ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="portfolio-nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">ALL</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Advert/Flyers</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Branding</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a pseudo element that will get placed in the first column pushing the other to start from the second one:

```css
#wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

#portfolio-nav ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#portfolio-nav ul:before {
  content: "";
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="portfolio-nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">ALL</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Advert/Flyers</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Branding</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or you can make the first element to start from the second column and the other will follow:

```css
#wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

#portfolio-nav ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#portfolio-nav ul > :first-child {
  grid-column:2;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="portfolio-nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">ALL</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Advert/Flyers</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Branding</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also modify you grid definition like below:

```css
#wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

#portfolio-nav {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 4fr 1fr;
}
#portfolio-nav ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-column:2;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="portfolio-nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">ALL</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Advert/Flyers</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Branding</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also consider padding to replace the empty columns:

```css
#wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

#portfolio-nav ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  padding:0 calc(100%/6);
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="portfolio-nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">ALL</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Advert/Flyers</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Branding</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just place the first `li` in the second column using `grid-column: 2` - see demo below:

```css
#wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

#portfolio-nav ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

ul li:first-child {
  grid-column: 2; /* added */
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="portfolio-nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">ALL</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Advert/Flyers</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Branding</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```